# Are args in pre-commit-config.yaml overwriting args in pre-commit-hooks.yaml?

Tags: pre-commit.com

We have specified some 'args' in the pre-commit-hooks.yaml file.

If now 'args' are also specified in the pre-commit-config.yaml are these added to the default ones or are these overwriting the default ones?

From the official documentation it is not clear to me what happens!

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, they overwrite receiving their defaults from `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml`

from [the docs](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-configyaml---hooks)

> All optional keys will receive their default from the repository's configuration.

if you want to specify arguments that are ~always honored, specify them in `entry` such as `entry: autopep8 -i` (this can still be overridden by the consuming repository, though it is less likely)